# T is a "single rooted" relation, show intersection of image is image of intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

T is a "single rooted" relation, show $\bigcap\limits_{x\in A}T[x]\subseteq T[\bigcap A]$.

A "single rooted" relation is a relation for which $y\in \mathrm{ran}\ T$ implies there is a unique $x$ for which $<x,y>\in\ T$.

The reverse direction is easy (i.e. these sets are actually equal) and does not rely on T being single rooted. There is a proof for the original direction as well.

$y \in\bigcap\limits_{x\in A}T[x]$ means for each $x \in A$,  $y \in T[x]$, so there exists a $z$ (which depends on $x$ so we will call it $z_x$) such that $z_x \in x$ and $<z_x,y> \in T$. But T is single rooted so all the $z_x's$ are the same for every $x$, say $z$. Hence for each $x\in A$, we have  $z \in x$ or $z \in \bigcap A$. And also $<z,y> \in T$, so $y \in T[\bigcap A]$.

What I am struggling with is changing the above proof into a a proof which  uses logic ONLY (I've done this successfully for every other set identity I've come across so far!). i.e. no words and each step is justified similar to the proof below. I can ALMOST get there, but not quite. If anyone can help, that would be most appreciated.

Here is the proof when "A" is {A,B}. i.e. T[A] $\cap$ T[B] $\subseteq$T[$A\cap B$].

$y \in T[A] \cap T[B]$
$\iff (y \in T[A] \wedge y \in T[B])$
$\iff \exists x(x \in A \wedge <x,y> \in T) \wedge \exists z (z \in B\wedge <z,y> \in T)))$
$\iff \exists x(\exists z((x \in A \wedge <x,y> \in T) \wedge (z \in B\wedge <z,y> \in T)))$
$\iff \exists x(\exists z((x \in A \wedge <x,y> \in T) \wedge (x \in B)
))$ As $x=z$ because T is single rooted.
$\iff \exists x((x \in A \wedge <x,y> \in T) \wedge (x \in B)
)$
$\iff \exists x(x \in A \cap B \wedge <x,y> \in T)$
$\iff y \in T[A\cap B] $

Comment: Ok, I think I have a new approach which will work. I’ll post here tmw as it’s late here! It’s quite a bit different than my other proofs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution (using fitch type natural deduction, I could use a more natrual style, but there are a lot of assumptions, and it gets confusing). Basically its a combination of the first and second proofs above. I assume A is non-empty, assume an element x in A, show this means there is an element z such that z is in x and <z,y> is in T. Then asume an arbitrary element in A and show this implies our z above is in this arbitrary element (using single rootedness). We can then show y is the image of the intersection of A.

[image]