# Show that for any arbitrary relation $R (D \cap E) = R(D) \cap R(E)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

So I'm supposed to prove that given any arbitrary relation $R \subseteq A \times B$ And given two subsets of $A$, $D$ and $E$, the following equality holds $R (D \cap E) = R(D) \cap R(E)$. I was able to prove that $R (D \cap E) \subseteq R(D) \cap R(E)$, but I'm pretty sure that the subset relationship doesn't go the other way around, in fact I think I found a counterexample. Consider the sets $A = \{a, b\}$ and $B = \{1\}$, then consider the relation $R \subseteq A \times B$ given by $R = \{(a,1), (b,1)\}$. Lastly consider the subsets of $A$, $D = \{a\}$ and $E = \{b\}$. Then if I'm not mistaken:
$R (D \cap E) = R(\emptyset) = \emptyset$ and $R(D) \cap R(E) = \{1\} \cap \{1\} = \{1\}$
So am I correct on my observation that the subset relation only goes one way but not the other? Is there an error on the book I'm reading? Thanks for your help!

Comment: In your example, I think $R(D)=\{(a,1)\}$ and $R(E)=\{(b,1)\}$. Hence $R(D) \cap R(E)= \phi .$

Comment: @LiKwokKeung Here's how the author defines $R(X)$ for a relation $R \subseteq A \times B$: $R(X) = \{ y \in B | (x, y) \in R \text{ for some } x \in X\}$

Comment: It only works in one direction. If R is “single rooted” it works in both directions. See my proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4483446/t-is-a-single-rooted-relation-show-intersection-of-image-is-image-of-intersec/4484171#4484171

Comment: And I think your counter-example is correct :).